How to get the complete log from the blazemeter run?
I want to know the complete logs of the jmeter script through the Blazemeter.
If we want to get the log of Jmeter script which ran locally that can be achieved by listener component View Results Tree where we can see all the details about each and every step i.e requestbody and responsebody etc.
Is there any way to get the same when we run the jmx file in Blazemeter?
I gone through the log folder in the Blazemeter where I found three log i.e artifact folder, bzt.log and system.log.
In the artifact folder there is a file named error.jtl which consists of the error results occured in the blazmeter run that can be parsed through the jmeter GUI.
But I am looking for the successful results as well as the response body contains some important message which needs to be captured.

I don't think it's possible mainly because it violates JMeter Best Practices, storing all response data will cause massive disk IO and can ruin your test.
BlazeMeter uses Taurus under the hood hence you can have only what Taurus produces
One of options is artificially causing Samplers failures via Response Assertion, you can come up with an assertion which will cause all Samplers to fail so they will be stored into error.jtl file. Once you finish debugging you can disable the assertion.
Another option is using JSR223 PostProcessor with the code like
log.info(prev.getResponseDataAsString())

this way you will get responses in jmeter.log file.
You can also How to Open a Support Ticket, it might be the case BlazeMeter has the possibility to enable storing of extra artifacts and they can do this for you as an exception
